# read complex json files using python

Tags: python, json

How to read json file and the write the data id value and room number into dictionary or arrays using python, the actual file is bigger than this, and i posted some a dummy file with sample keys, and values.

c_data.json

```
{"data": [
      { "id": K8908,
        "use": "reception",
        "sq-ft": 50,
        "price": 75
      },
      { "id": Q9090,
        "use": "waiting",
        "sq-ft": 250,
        "price": 75
      },
      { "room-number": 101,
        "use": "examination",
        "sq-ft": 125,
        "price": 150
      },
      { "room-number": 103,
        "use": "examination",
        "sq-ft": 125,
        "price": 150
      },
      { "room-number": 104,
        "use": "office",
        "sq-ft": 150,
        "price": 100
      },

    ],
    "parking": {
      "location": "premium",
      "style": "covered",
      "price": 750
    }
 }
```

Comment: You literally didn't google `python json`, did you? Because if you had, this would be blindingly obvious https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html - sorry for the toxic tone, but this is seriously aggravating.

Answer (score 1):

```
import simplejson as json

with open('data.json') as json_file:
   data = json.loads(json_file)
   print data
```

You can do this.

Answer (score 0):

Use json module.

```
import json

with open("myfile.json") as f:
  mydata = json.load(f)["data"]

for item in mydata:
  print(f"""
    id: {item["id"]}
    price: {item["price"}
  """)
```

Read docs, search SO before asking, and so on, and so on.......

Answer (score 0):

you can use "nested_lookup" library.
https://pypi.org/project/nested-lookup/

> " The nested_lookup package provides many Python functions for working with deeply nested documents. A document in this case is a a mixture of Python dictionary and list objects typically derived from YAML or JSON. "

I found it very helpful for my project.
For start get the keys and the values to lists.

```
from nested_lookup import nested_lookup #get key and json - return value
from nested_lookup import get_all_keys #Returns a list of keys.

list_id = nested_lookup(id , JSON)
room_number = nested_lookup(room-number, JSON)
```

then you can run a loop on these lists(or something else) and add them to a dictionary.

```
#function that get key and value and add to dictionary 
def add_key_value_to_dic(key, value):
   if key in dic_js:
      pass print('error')
   else:
      dic_js[key] = value
```

Answer (score 0):

for a big JSON file, you can use the library `ujson`

> https://github.com/ultrajson/ultrajson

```py
import ujson
with open('data.json') as json_file:
    for item in ujson.dumps(obj):
      print(item['id'], item['room-number'])
```

for super JSON file, such as 20Gb, you can use redis to save, and read.
please enjoy it.